# The Fourth Parameter and Why isn't MVC 3 SelectList Pre-Selecting an Option?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use the SelectList overload

[SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx)

In the controller:

```
List<MyObj> MyObjList;
MyObj mySel = (from o in MyObjList where o.Name == selectedName select c)
              .SingleOrDefault();

// Variant A:
var list = new SelectList(TENANTS, "Code", "Name", (object)(mySel.Name));

// Variant B:
var list = new SelectList(TENANTS, "Code", "Name", (object)(mySel));
ViewBag.ListForDropdown = list;
```

In the view:

```
var list = (List<MyObj>)ViewBag.ListForDropdown;
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PropOfTypeMyObject, list, "--- Select One ---")
```

The DropDownList renders correctly, but no values are selected.  I confirmed in the debugger that `mySel` is an instance from the `MyObjList` collection.

Is the 4th parameter supposed to be an instance of an object that is in `MyObjList`?  What am I missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in `.Name`, which is the Text property of the select list.  Use `.Code` instead - the Value property.